# Java key sequenced key combo

Tags: java, sequence, combinations, keystroke

In Java, I can easily handle key combinations by using flags to track which key is press, and which is not pressed, and see if all flags are set to do the action of the key-combination. What I cannot do is handle sequenced key combo, i.e. pressing one key and releasing it then pressing another and releasing and and so on within a small period in between each key (500ms or 1000ms). It is something similar to the one used in fighting games, however, this is for desktop application's purposes. How can I manage timed events to clear the flags when time has exceeded the period.